# how can i access to <tag key = ... value = .../> which is IN a <node > using libxml2?

Tags: c, openstreetmap, libxml2

I'm trying to parse an OSM file using libxml2. 
Here is a part of osm file:

```
   <node id="368138" lat="48.8546445" lon="2.3627305" user="Pieren"
    uid="17286" visible="true" version="3" changeset="4490579"
     timestamp="2010-04-21T20:34:49Z">
   <tag k="highway" v="traffic_signals"/>
   </node>
```

I'm need to get the key and value of the tag. But i don't know how. I tried to access using

```
xmlHasProp(node,(const xmlChar*)"tag")
```

but I think tag is not considered as a prop of a `node`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The straightforward option is to walk from the root node to the descendent node you're looking for. Child nodes of an XML document or element can be accessed as a linked list via the `children` and `next` pointers. For example, assuming `node` is an OSM `node` element:

```
for (xmlNode *cur = node->children; cur; cur = cur->next) {
    if (cur->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE
        && xmlStrcmp(cur->name, BAD_CAST "tag") == 0) {
        /* Found "tag" element. */
    }
}
```

Another option is to use *libxml2*'s XPath engine. It allows you enumerate nodes using an [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) expression.

Have a look at the [examples](http://www.xmlsoft.org/examples/) on the *libxml2* website.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with libxml2 but according to the documentation `xmlHasProp()` searches for XML *attributes*. In [OSM XML](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML), a node has various attributes like *lat*, *lon* and so on. Tags however are not modeled as attributes, they are child elements instead. To access tags you have to iterate over the *children* of the node.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I also tried that, but knowing that a _tag_ is inside a _node_, it's not a child element

Comment: Why shouldn't it be a child element? That's the basic structure of XML files.